# How to make a drop-down which give output on every onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a Drop Down Select element which have 3 options lets name it as X,Y,Z having values 1,2,3 respectively.Now my question is to how to set a conditions or what to do next to show graph every time when i select option as earlier it only shows the graph of first option which i select first because of onchange function occured already.

Comment: Could you provide what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. This will give you current option selected, based on which you can perform your next operations.

HTML:

```
<select id="select" onchange="onOptionChange();"> 
  <option value="1">X</option> 
  <option value="2">Y</option> 
  <option value="3">Z</option> 
</select>
```

JS:

```
function onOptionChange() {
  console.log($('#select').val());    //prints current option selected
}
```

Comment: Then after getting value how can i put condition on that?

Comment: Just test it as:
   `if ($('#select').val() == 1) {
      //your code
   } else if ($('#select').val() == 2) {
     //your code
   } else {
     //your code
   }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="ddrp1">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">X</option>
  <option value="2">Y</option>
  <option value="3">Z</option>
</select>
```

Assuming an id for dropdown select is ddrp1.

```
$("#ddrp1").on("change", function() {
  var selectedVal = this.value;
  var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  var selectedVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
  var selectedText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
  // set your condition here based on selectedText or selectedVal to display graph
}​​​​);​
```

Comment: This works for jquery 1.7 for lower version use $("#ddrp1").change(function(){ // same as above });